# Неправильно отображаются буквы

Tags: кодировка, php

Вообщем в базе данных все записано в cp1251, сайт тоже на этой кодировке ставил header в файлах бесполезно, везде ставлю эту кодировку cp1251, а толку никакого - все равно отображаются одни вопросики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте после mysql_connect

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET collation_connection='utf8_general_ci");
mysql_query("SET collation_server='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_server='utf8'");
```

utf-8 надо заменить на свою кодировку, которую решили использовать.

А также проверьте кодировки таблиц БД, кодировки столбцов БД (в структуре таблицы). А также не помешает проверить кодировку по умолчанию на сервере.

Для особого эффекта проверьте кодировки самих файлов, и что написано в теге head. Всех лучше кодировку меняет Dreamviewer и phpDesigner.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых хорошим тоном считается использования utf-8.
Во-вторых, чтобы не было проблем с кодировками:
бд должна быть в нужной кодировке, а также все файлы проекта должны быть сохранены в этой же кодировке. В html прописывайте кодировку в теге meta, а в php отправляйте header с указанием этой кодировки(приоритет здесь имеет php).

Answer (score 1):

В .htacess

```
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
php_value default_charset cp1251
php_value default_charset cp1251
```

Answer (score 0):

После подключение к базе напишите `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");`

Answer (score 0):

Или так попробуйте:

> mysql_query('set character_set_client="cp1251"');
>
> mysql_query('set character_set_results="cp1251"');
>
> mysql_query('set collation_connection="cp1251_general_ci"'); //Тут зависит от настроек базы;